# Unable to render menu in theme

Tags: routes, theming

I'm creating a custom theme in Drupal 7 but I'm having trouble getting it to render the menu

I'm using the following code in page-front.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($page['main_menu']): ?>
    <div id="main-menu"><div class="section clearfix">
<?php print render($page['main_menu']); ?>
    </div></div>
```

But it does not render anything. I have double checked that a menu exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$page['main_menu'] is not menu. It's the region with name main_menu. You can put there any block what you want. You can configure blocks on this page admin/structure/block

But in the basic drupal themes the main menu can be available in this variable $main_menu in the template page.tpl.php